# Why are the "donkey" and the "butt" both named "ass"?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

Is there any similarity between them that they have the same name, or is the reason something different of having a physical similarity?

I found different meanings for both, but none of them clarified the matter of naming them the same in vulgar English speaking.

Comment: [This](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ass&searchmode=none) doesn't answer your question, but it's a good place to start the conversation.

Comment: Actually it does answer the question by providing the etymology of both arse and ass and showing how arse dropped the r in the US.

Comment: "Butt" and "ass" only mean bottom in American English. They do not, in England and the rest of the UK which use the English words *bum* and *arse*. This question should be tagged as American English.

Comment: Even more confusingly for people who equate it with a mammal's rear end, "butt" can refer to pork shoulder meat or to the bumping action of an animal's head or horns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a historical accident—they’re really two different words.

In the sense *buttocks*, the word goes back to OE *ærs*, and beyond that to Proto Indo-European: there are cognates in Greek, Hittite and Old Irish.  This is reflected in the ordinary British English *arse*—the {r} is dropped only in US English.

In the sense *donkey*, the word goes back to OE *assa*, derived (it is thought) via Celtic from Latin *asinus* (which may itself be of Middle Eastern origin).

See the *Online Etymological Dictionary*, s.v. [**arse**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=arse&searchmode=none) and [**ass**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ass&searchmode=none), and the *Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. [**arse**](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/464/mode/2up) and [**ass**](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/496/mode/2up).

Answer (score 7):

Butt was originally (and in British English still is) *arse*. The donkey is *ass*. In American English these words merged into a single *ass*. The etymology has nothing to do with the similarity of the animal to a behind.

Comment: Armen, no. In England and the rest of the UK, the word is *bum*. See this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bum_1?q=bum Using "butt" with this meaning, sounds distinctly American, from an English and British perspective.