# Word-part meaning/origin of "-cock", as in "shuttlecock", "ballcock", and "sillcock"

Tags: etymology, suffixes

Okay, apart from the American slang term, or the reference to a male chicken, what is the meaning of the syllable "cock"?

For example, shuttlecock ... in badminton. Or, as I'm doing housework and learning about plumbing, a "ballcock" valve in a toilet, or a "sillcock" valve in pipes?

Does it refer to a specific shape, or a mechanism or something? Which might make sense for the valves, but then what about the shuttlecock?

Comment: The *full* Oxford English Dictionary just says the ***-cock*** part of ***ballcock, shuttlecock,...*** comes from the male bird sense. Which is ALSO the origin for ***cock** = penis* (& derivatives like ***cock-up** = shambles*) AND ***cock** = stand up straight* (as a fishing float, or ***cocky** = overconfident*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are animal names used as vulgar slang for body parts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112729/why-are-animal-names-used-as-vulgar-slang-for-body-parts)

Comment: Nah, I saw that other question, and it's related I guess vaguely, but I'm not asking about genitalia, or animals or the relation between them. But just about this syllable in relation more specifically NOT related to genitalia.

Comment: Odd that it would be related to the male bird meaning, as I don't really see how that could possibly relate to the plumbing valves. Although I COULD see it relating to the shuttlecock, in that the feathers on it are similar to a bird (and I'd assume originally were from a bird), and could also look reminiscent of the often fancier plumage on male birds.

Comment: Plumbing valves often go up & down, "bobbing" like a fishing float. Especially primitive early designs where the supply is closed off by something floating to the top (of water in a tank, say, at which point the tank is full so you want to block off the supply). And I expect a shuttlecock is to do with moving *straight (upright-ish).*

Comment: Some (but not all) dictionaries give the tap/faucet definition as in _ballcock_ and _stopcock_. I thought I had read that that was the origin of the slang meaning, but evidently Oxford doesn't think so.

Comment: My favorite source for etymology, https://www.etymonline.com/word/cock, claims the origin of the valve meaning is not clear.

Comment: @eidylon: It's related to the *crowing* of cock fowl, not to their plumbing. Marking territory. Not just bird males mark territory, but cocks are conspicuous, noisy crowers. (Not to mention that they often crow standing erect and prominent on top of a tree, barn, etc.) Hens don't crow, generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymonline suggests:

***[Cock(n.2)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cock)***

> in various mechanical senses, such as "turn-valve of a faucet" (early 15c.), of uncertain connection with [cock (n.1)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cock). Perhaps all are based on real or fancied resemblances not now obvious; German has hahn "cock" in many of the same senses.